# Accessing a Session object from Razor _Layout.cshml

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Building an MVC 3 app with Razor and I have some information persisted in the Session scope that will be used in the _Layout file.

I have no clue as to what is the best way to implement this. Some of this information is used to determine what is rendered in the header.

I have a CurrentUser object stored in Session scope

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You could just access the HttpContext in the layout file

```
@HttpContext.Current.Session["Whatever"].ToString()
```

or, if you want access to the user object you could just create an object in the page and assign it

```
@{ CurrentUser user = (CurrentUser)HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"]; }
```

Then later in your code...

```
@user.Name
```

Comment: Hey thanks.. that works but now i feel dirty cause I had to add an @using directive.. isn't there a way to use a ViewModel in your _Layout?

Comment: If it will make you feel cleaner, you could add your namespace to the default list of Razor usings in the Views\Web.config file.

Comment: You could also wrap this up in a common base class for your view models.  I believe you may be able to use that base class from your _Layout page.

Comment: sorry, lil off topic but, is there a: Session.isNew?

Comment: There's a `Session_Started()` that's when the session is created for the user

Answer (score 3):

An easier way to do it is using `Session` property directly from the view (`HttpContext.Current.` prefix should not be necessary at all):

```
@(CurrentUser)Session["CurrentUser"]
```