# access session variable from layout page ASP.NET MVC3 RAZOR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to access a session variable from my layout master page, but you cant have a model in a layout page, so how do I access this variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing a Session object from Razor \_Layout.cshml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381189/accessing-a-session-object-from-razor-layout-cshml)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@{var sessionvar = Session["myVar"] as FooType;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move that logic to a child action and call the child action from the master page using `@Html.Action(...)`.

To answer the question, use the `Session` property.