# How to AccessSimpleMemberShipprovider properties of current user ASP.net MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a razor .cshtml view in MVC4 and I want to print a field of my userprofile class.  I understand I can get the Username from User.Identity.Name but I don't know how to access the other properties of the currently logged in user in the partial.  Do I need to do this in my controller and reference it in my view?  If so is there a controller that is available to all views so I am not setting this variable in every controller?  Is there a simple way to access the current users properties as defined in the UserProfile model class right in the view?  To give some context.  I have my model as...

```
 public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        //Added to round out requirements for site user profile
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Site { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to access the FirstName in the view.  If I get it in the controller then I will need to do it in all controllers since this is a page partial for all pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to put it in a session variable since it is not critical, sensitive, or effects the stability of the application.  In my controller on login or registration I set the session variable with...

```
var context = new UsersContext();
var curuser = context.UserProfiles.First(p => p.UserName == model.UserName);
Session["FName"] = curuser.FirstName;
```

I got this from Pro ASP.NET MVC and from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352218/how-do-i-manage-profiles-using-simplemembership) post.  And in my Razor view I use this derived from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381189/accessing-a-session-object-from-razor-layout-cshml) post.

```
@HttpContext.Current.Session["FName"].ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the controller action that is serving the partial view put FirstName in the ViewBag.
If there are more properties that you would like to return then create a ViewModel for them and make the controller action return that.

Comment: since this is a partial that is on all site pages and will be from different controllers I would need to do that in all controllers.  I suppose I can but I was looking for a way to do it once.  Like in Rails there is an application_controller that is accessible to all views so any variables in that are site wide.