# How to hide submenu in my razor _Layout?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, mvvm

I have my menu toolbar in my _Layout, and sometimes I would like to hide submenu, depends on who is connected (administrator or user).

User profile is stored in userViewModel, but I can't set userViewModel in my _layout.

Comment: so basically, if user_profile == administrator, show menu toolbar?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381189/accessing-a-session-object-from-razor-layout-cshml

Comment: Use ViewData or ViewBag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render menu toolbar in the _Layout by means of

`@Html.Action("MenuToolbar","Controller")`

```
public ViewResult MenuToolbar()
{
  if (user.isAdministrator) 
     return View("MenuToolbar");
  else return View("Empty");
}
```

OR you can use more universal approach:

```
public static  MvcHtmlString ActionBaseRole(this HtmlHelper value, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues , IPrincipal user)
 {     
   bool userHasRequeredRole = false;
   Type t = Type.GetType((string.Format("MyProject.Controllers.{0}Controller",controllerName))); // MyProject.Controllers... replace on you namespace
   MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod(actionName);
   var attr = (method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute), true) as AuthorizeAttribute);
   if (attr != null)
   {
      string[] methodRequeredRoles = attr.Roles.Split(',');
      userHasRequeredRole = methodRequeredRoles.Any(r => user.IsInRole(r.Trim())); // user roles check in depends on implementation authorization in you site  
                                                                                            // In a simple version that might look like                                                                         
   }
   else userHasRequeredRole = true; //method don't have Authorize Attribute
   return userHasRequeredRole ? value.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues) : MvcHtmlString.Empty; 
 }
```

In this case you need just put 
`[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, OtherRole")]`  befor an action.

Comment: Thanks, your first solution was exactly what I'm looking for. Sometimes it's hard to find simplest way ... :-)